# Regarding the "You didn't need it anyway" achievement

Tags: achievements, antimatter-dimensions

In the game [Antimatter Dimensions](https://ivark.github.io/AntimatterDimensions/), there is an achievement called "You didn't need it anyway", which is achievable when you: *Infinity without having any 8th Antimatter Dimensions.*

According to the [guide on Fandom](https://antimatter-dimensions.fandom.com/wiki/Guide#1-33_total_IP:_Early-Infinity_(6_hours_to_6_days)), it seems to be easily achievable even if you're at early Infinity section of the game. So, the guide says...

> Reach Infinite antimatter without having any 8th Dimensions. To do this, get 6 IP worth of upgrades, buy as many Galaxies and Dimension Boosts as allowed within the boundaries of Infinity, then instead of Maxing all, Buy Max Tickspeed and buy 10 of all Dimensions except for the 8th. That way you can get a small boost to Dimensions 1-7.

Now, the problem is, the guide suggests you to *buy as many Galaxies and Dimension Boosts*. Even my limited knowledge about this game knows this is wrong, since Galaxies cannot be bought if you don't buy Dimension Boosts 5 times, which **requires** you to be own some of 8th Dimensions (and Galaxy itself requires you to be own some of 8th Dimensions).

This conflicts to the achievement's description, since it says *without having any 8th Antimatter Dimensions*. So, is the guide just wrong, or am I understanding the game wrongly? If so, how am I taking that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guide is mostly correct, but it is missing some context, possibly to avoid spoilers. If you scroll down in the guide, you can see what allows this to work:

> Automated Dimension Boosts (C10): Very slow Challenge with no special
>  tactics. You'll probably need 3 Galaxies because you only have 6
>  dimensions meaning no Sacrifice and slower polynomial production.
>  Doing this Challenge fulfills the You didn't need it anyway
>  achievement as you cannot buy Eighth Dimensions anyway. You must get
>  the "All Galaxies are twice as strong" upgrade for this challenge to
>  be possible.

Without this context, the advice in the header appears contradictory and should probably be removed or tweaked. I can't access the page's history because it was moved, but I suspect that this was added later, possibly by someone who didn't fully understand the constraints.

Comment: You can access the page history. It's [here](https://antimatter-dimensions.fandom.com/wiki/Help:Guide?action=history) (for now, anyway)

Comment: I've actually unknowingly unlocked the achievement during the run, and I've completed the C10, so I guess that was the reason. Plus, I've noticed that other page - [Achievement](https://antimatter-dimensions.fandom.com/wiki/Achievements) - states that : *You can buy 8th ADs in the same Infinity, as long as you have 0 when you crunch.* Getting Galaxy resets ADs, so it seems to be completable during normal run.